# Drupal 7:: create a page with views to show all the contents not authored by current user

Tags: 7, views

I am creating two page with views module. First page will show all the contents authored by current user. Second page will show all the contents that current user can view but not created by him.

I am trying it with contextual filter but no luck yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, Create a content view with a relation **Content: Author**, than you will get **User: Current** in side the add filter, Add this filter to your view
[image]

Use **No** for Second problem.